# Trouble reading file and filling in a chart

Tags: java

Develop a top-down design and write a program to produce a bar chart of gourmet-popcorn production for a cooperative farm group on a farm-by-farm basis.

The input to the program is a series of data sets, one per line, with each set representing the production for one farm.
Each data set consists of the name of a farm. Followed by a comma and one or more spaces, a decimal number representing acres planted, one or more spaces, and an integer representing the number of pint jars of popcorn produced for that farm.
The output is a bar chart that identifies each farm and displays its production in pints of corn per acre.
The output is a single line for each farm, with the name of the farm starting in the first column on a line and the bar chart starting in column 30. Each mark in the bar chart represents 25 pint jars of popcorn per acre.
The production goal for the year is 500 jars per acre. A vertical bar should appear in the chart for farms with production that does not meet this goal, and a special mark is used for farms with production greater than or equal to 500 jars per acre.
For example, given the input file

```
Orville’s Acres, 114.8 43801
Hoffman’s Hills, 77.2 36229
Jiffy Quick Farm, 89.4 24812
Jolly Good Plantation, 183.2 104570
Organically Grown Inc., 45.5 14683
```

the output would be:

```
              Popcorn Co-op
          Production in Hundreds
          of Pint Jars per Acre
Farm Name                 1   2   3   4   5   6
                         ---|---|---|---|---|---|
Orville's Acres         ***************    |
Hoffman's Hills         ****************** |
Jiffy Quick Farm        ***********        |
Jolly Good Plantation   *******************#**
Organically Grown Inc.  ************       |
```

I have so far,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Popcorn
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("Enter file name: "); 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String file = in.next();  
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file)); 

    int jar;           
    double acre;
    String farm;
    String amt;


    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.printf("%30s",  "Popcorn Co-op"); 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("\n%55s", "Production in Hundreds");
    System.out.printf("\n%56s", "of Pint Jars per Acre\n");
    System.out.printf("Farm Name %46s", "1   2   3   4   5   6\n");
    System.out.printf("%58s", "---|---|---|---|---|---|\n");


    while (input.hasNextLine())  
    {
      String inputFileLine = input.nextLine();

      if (inputFileLine.isEmpty()) 
      {
      }
      else
      {
        farm = inputFileLine.substring(0,inputFileLine.indexOf(',')); 
        String inputFileLine2 = inputFileLine.substring(inputFileLine.indexOf(',') + 1);
        Scanner line = new Scanner(inputFileLine2); 
        acre = line.nextDouble(); 
        jar = line.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println(farm); 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I am completely stumped on how to read the file and fill in the chart with asterisks.

Comment: Did you just post your whole assignment lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is CLEARLY a homework assignment I'm going to avoid giving you the answer like everybody else. You'll never learn how to write code if you are given the answers online so for your own development I will merely try to assist.

**What you have**

- You already have a system that reads a file and extracts some of the
  information and prints the information extracted in a formatted way.

**What you lack**

- You're not fully grasping the math or logic behind the main request of the program, which is the generating of the asterisks.

**Pointers**

For starters I'd use scratch paper and think this out logically. You know how many acres each farm has and how many pints of popcorn were produced. Therefore, you know the number of jars per acre that have been produced.

You will need to divide that number by 25 in order to meet the requirement:

```
Each mark in the bar chart represents 25 pint jars of popcorn per acre.
```

So you're 2 mathematical calculations away from knowing how many stars go into a bar. Once you know that, I believe a simple loop should help you wrap this project up.

Lastly, I think you'll want to use `printf()` to print out your results as it allows for the flexibility you need to format the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same assignment…

we have an equation…

```
 int asterisks = jars/acres/25;
```

//then use a for loop

```
for(int i = 1; i <= asterisks; i++)
{
System.out.println('*');`
}
```

Then work your way through the details...

Comment: If you have some problems…incensefrenzie2006@gmail.com

Comment: I keep getting "variable jar might not have been initialized" and "variable acre might not have been initialized" but I have my code set up to read the line for those values